# SignalR/CoffeeScript Hub callback issue

Tags: knockout.js, signalr, signalr-hub

This works fine

```
class Window.AppViewModel
    message : ko.observable("")
    chatMessages : ko.observableArray()
    canSendMessage : ko.observable(false)
    Window.sHub.addMsg = (data) =>  
        @::chatMessages.push(data)
```

whereas this

```
class Window.AppViewModel
    constructor : ->
        @message = ko.observable("")
        @chatMessages = ko.observableArray()
        @canSendMessage = ko.observable(false)
        Window.sHub.addMsg = (data) =>  
            @chatMessages.push(data)
```

Results in my server side hub **recieving** server messages but it can't make any callbacks.

What am I missing here???  This is driving me up the wall.  Obviously the prototype based solution will work because it's making everything "static" but I'm crippled because I can't write nicely separated code at the moment.

Is there any way to see what the hub is trying to invoke??  The SignalR documentation talks about tracing/logging but never explains how.

Comment: $.connection.hub.logging = true

Comment: THanks but this only succeeded in telling me that the event made it back to the page.  Still can't figure out why my handler isn't called.

Comment: Maybe you spelled it incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All wired client events can be found by adding a small snippet to the "On" anonymous function in jquery.SignalR in the hubProxy prototype

So now it looks something like this

```
   on: function (eventName, callback) {
            /// <summary>Wires up a callback to be invoked when a invocation request is received from the server hub.</summary>
            /// <param name="eventName" type="String">The name of the hub event to register the callback for.</param>
            /// <param name="callback" type="Function">The callback to be invoked.</param>
            var self = this;

            // Normalize the event name to lowercase
            eventName = eventName.toLowerCase();
            console.log(eventName + " callback was registered on the client");
            $(self).bind(eventNamespace + eventName, function (e, data) {
                callback.apply(self, data);
            });
            self.subscribed = true;
            return self;
        }
```

And gives you nice output of what client methods can be called back from the server

Also, I learned that CreateHubProxies (reflects through the callbacks you add) is only called once for an entire hub.Start()--So all methods must be added to the hub proxy **before** you start.

This should definitely be on the github wiki.  It makes sense but it isn't obvious.

Edit : It would make sense to allow you to call CreateHubProxies multiple times.  People are accustom to writing Knockout.js code in a way where they delay allocating a viewmodel until a certain event happens--if your viewmodel has any SignalR callbacks, this isn't impossible.  Having to create all of your viewmodels upfront is a bit of a kludge.  You could even keep it pretty lean by keeping a list of proxy members already generated and excluding them.

Comment: So, what would you recommend as the proper procedure when you're using nested KnockoutJs VM's? I had assumed that the VM could call signalr hubs to get data but as you pointed out that required registration of all your VMs before .start().

Comment: I was forced to do the following (with hub callbacks registered in each ViewModel's constructor)

Window.sHub = $.connection.worldHub
Window.LoginVM = new Window.LoginViewModel
Window.AppVM = new Window.AppViewModel
Window.RegisterVM = new Window.RegisterViewModel 

And then I called start.  A bit ugly.  If you need to do true initialization separately in your viewmodels, you'll need to use an IsInitialized variable and have what amounts to a second constructor.  Covers all scenarios, is managable, and ensures everything happens in order.